# What's the encoding of peers6 dictionary in tracker's response?

Tags: php, bittorrent

I decided to add ipv6 support to my PHP tracker.

From the [BEP](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0007.html):

> In case a compact response is requested, the tracker MAY add another
> key to the response; peers6. This key has the same layout as peers in
> compact mode, but instead of using 6 bytes per endpoint, 18 bytes are
> used. peers6 contains address-port pairs where the addresses are all
> IPv6. Examples
>
> Example response:
>
> d8:intervali1800e5:peers6:iiiipp6:peers618:iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiippe

I didn't quite get that 18 bytes point.

I give ipv4 peers list through bencode via

```
$peers  .= pack('Nn', $row['ip'], $row['port']);
```

What format should I use now?

Comment: "_I didn't quite get that 18 bytes point._" IPv4 addresses are four bytes (32 bits), plus the other two makes six bytes. IPv6 addresses are 16 bytes (128 bits), plus the other two makes 18 bytes.

Comment: @ron-mauping That is, I do not need to change anything in the string format, I just need to feed the ip address and port to the same function?